# Active record store two objects in one database record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

suppose I have a legacy database that I can't refactor in any way.

I have a database table where a record contains fields that should belong to two logical different objects whose relation is actually 1:1, now to have my code cleaner I would like to split this single object in two in my application model.

So suppose now I have a table with n fields where the first x fields should be mapped by a model in my rails app, and the remaining n - x fields should be mapped in another model, is there a simple way to achieve this in active records?

Thanks,
Gnagno

Comment: Well, it does not seem to be a great design, but it is obviously doable. You would need to create default_scope with select listing all the columns, undefine or override attribute readers and create one-to-one association with_foreign_key being id. I would expect it would work, however it might be more pain than gain. Is there no way you could spit those into two tables?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can't split those tables because it's a legacy database, and there's another application persisting on the same db, developed by another team on which I don't have any control.